Possibilities of Bypassing the Constructed attributes for input sanitization
Hello All I have implemented the following pattern for sanitizing the XSS input. Can you help me if there is any possibility or any payload that can be constructed in bypassing the below patterns
str = str.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", ""); str = str.replaceAll("\\&lt;.*?\\&gt;", "");
private static final String XSS_PATTERN = "<(?:img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*[^>]+\\s+onerror\\s*=\\s*\"?[^>]*prompt\\(.*\\)[^>]*>|script\\s*>[^<]*alert\\(.*\\)[^<]*</script\\s*)>|<\\s*img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*[^>]+\\s+onerror\\s*=\\s*\"?[^>]*prompt\\(.*\\)[^>]*>|<\\s*img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*[^>]*\\b(onerror=eval\\(src\\))[^>]*>|script\\s*>.*\\</script\\s*>|style\\s*>.*\\</style\\s*>";
    private static final String XSS_PATTERN2 = "&lt;(?:img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*[^&gt;]+\\s+onerror\\s*=\\s*\"?[^&gt;]*prompt\\(.*\\)[^&gt;]*&gt;|script\\s*&gt;[^&lt;]*alert\\(.*\\)[^&lt;]*&lt;/script\\s*)&gt;|&lt;\\s*img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*[^&gt;]+\\s+onerror\\s*=\\s*\"?[^&gt;]*prompt\\(.*\\)[^&gt;]*&gt;|&lt;\\s*img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*[^&gt;]*\\b(onerror=eval\\(src\\))[^&gt;]*&gt;|script\\s*&gt;.*\\&lt;/script\\s*&gt;|style\\s*&gt;.*\\&lt;/style\\s*&gt;";


Have you tested in the regex is subject to ReDOS? Also it seems to handle literal and HTML Entity encoded angle brackets but I don't see any handling for charcode or URL encode. Why are you trying to home grow a solution for this? There are tons of libraries and WAFs that can do this for you and are far more widely tested.
